# GitHub device verification email not received

Tags: github

After reinstalling windows on my machine, i have tried to login to my Github account using the same user-name password stored in the browser with my Microsoft account...

with Sign in to GitHub
Username or email address page:
its seems to accept the credentials (tried with email as well with username) and then navigate to the next page saying:
Device verification code
We just sent your authentication code via email to y**************@hotmail.com.

But I never receive any email!!!
not in inbox or junk email beside the GitHub Community Summary..

i am afraid to try the Forgot password option - because perhaps it get the auth issue even worse.

Comment: Also not receiving the verification email.  Github has a bug problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the password seems to be a solution.

The email should arrive within a few minutes in case of setting a new password, even if you had problems in the authentication process.